# GORM one-to-many mapping doing eager fetching by default

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Using GORM/Grails 2.3.7/Hibernate 3.6, NO scaffolding.

It's my understanding Hibernate uses lazy loading, so why does my mapping eagerly fetch?

```
TEAM  ---has many-->  MAILBOX
```

.

```
class Team {
   Long id
   Long version

   static hasMany = [mailboxes:Mailbox]
   static mapping = {
      id       sqlType:'number', generator: 'native' 
      version  sqlType:'number'
   }

class Mailbox {
   Long id
   Team team

   static belongsTo = [team:Team]
   static mapping = {
      id       sqlType:'number', generator: 'native' 
   }
```

### Problem

When calling `Team.get(id)`, the returned object contains all mailboxes, fully instantiated. I was expecting mailboxes to be null unless invoking `team.getMailboxes()`, is the mapping wrong?

### Tried

Removed back-reference in Mailbox:

```
 class Mailbox {
      Long id
      //Team team
      static belongsTo = Team   //before [team:Team]
```

Had no impact,

Also confirmed from sql output Hibernate is eargerly fetching the mailboxes:

```
Hibernate: select team0_.id as id1_0_, team0_.version as version1_0_, team0_.name as name1_0_ from team team0_ where team0_.id=?
Hibernate: select mailboxes0_.team_mailboxes_id as team1_1_0_, mailboxes0_.mailbox_id as mailbox2_0_ from team_mailbox mailboxes0_ where mailboxes0_.team_mailboxes_id=?
Hibernate: select mailbox0_.id as id0_0_, mailbox0_.version as version0_0_, mailbox0_.name as name0_0_ from mailbox mailbox0_ where mailbox0_.id=?
```

I thought maybe it was related to hibernate cache, but I've disabled it:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    singleSession = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of lazy loading is wrong. If you define an object or collection to loaded lazily, it does NOT mean, that they should return a `null`. Instead, you get a `proxy` a `collection of proxies` back, which get "inflated" as soon as you explicitly access the properties of the lazy-loaded object

Comment: Understood, apologies if I was not clear, I'm not invoking `team.getMailboxes()`, yet mailboxes are fully-instantiated

Comment: hmmm, was the join table `team_mailbox` created by you or by GORM? Usually for o2m no join table is needed

Comment: I'm using `create-drop`, and Hibernate did _not_ create a join table, just `TEAM` and `MAILBOX` tables.

Comment: where this log record came from then?
`Hibernate: select mailboxes0_.team_mailboxes_id as team1_1_0_, mailboxes0_.mailbox_id as mailbox2_0_ from team_mailbox mailboxes0_ where mailboxes0_.team_mailboxes_id=?`

Comment: in o2m in the `mailbox` table should be a `team_id` field, that's it. I assume, there's something wrong with your setup...

Comment: Logging is from Hibernate/GORM using `logSql = true` ... Mailbox table has `id` and `team_id`, in addition to other properties I omitted for brevity.

Comment: the sql log should have contained 2 lines for team + mailbox fetch:
`select ... from team where id=?` and `select ... from mailbox where team_id=?`. Drop the join table manually and check again